# Webscraping Returns xml_nodeset 0 in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape this website. https://web.tmxmoney.com/earnings.php?qm_symbol=DOL specifically the table at the bottom of the screen.
I have tried countless of CSS and XPath but still get {xml_nodeset(0)}. I am looking for an intuitive answer rather than just the code.

Here are a few of my attempts.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

tbl = read_html('https://web.tmxmoney.com/earnings.php?qm_symbol=DOL')%>%
               html_nodes("table").[2]%>%html_table(fill = T)#no luck

tbl = read_html('https://web.tmxmoney.com/earnings.php?qm_symbol=DOL')%>%
               html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]')%>%html_table(fill = T)#node set(0)
```

I have tried countless others, using selector gadget and inspecting the source code. 
[image]

Comment: I suspect that the page is not fully populated right away, perhaps a solution is to use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html to start a browser session and then download it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't check the complete Terms of Service, so please be aware that scraping might not be legal.
The following should do the trick:

```
library(rvest)
library(data.table)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(RSelenium)

mybrowser <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox') 

link <- "https://web.tmxmoney.com/earnings.php?qm_symbol=DOL"
mybrowser$client$navigate(link)

mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_0")$getElementText()

html.table <-  mybrowser$client$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#DataTables_Table_0") 
webElem5txt <- html.table$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
df.table <- read_html(webElem5txt) %>% html_table() %>% data.frame(.)

mybrowser$server$stop()
# Excerpt of the data:
 > df.table
Var.1      Quarter.End        X..EPS.Actual X..EPS.Estimate X..Estimates X..Surprise X..Surprise.1       Date
1     NA 2019-07-31 (Q2 2020)          0.45            0.47            3       -0.02        -4.26% 2019-09-12
2     NA 2019-04-30 (Q1 2020)          0.33            0.33            4        0.00         0.00% 2019-06-13
3     NA 2019-01-31 (Q4 2019)          0.54            0.55            4       -0.01        -1.82% 2019-03-28
4     NA 2018-10-31 (Q3 2019)          0.41            0.42            3       -0.01        -2.38% 2018-12-06
5     NA 2018-07-31 (Q2 2019)          0.43            0.44            3       -0.01        -2.27% 2018-09-13
6     NA 2018-04-30 (Q1 2019)          0.31            0.31            3        0.00         0.00% 2018-06-07
7     NA 2018-01-31 (Q4 2018)          0.48            0.47            4        0.01         2.13% 2018-03-29
```

Comment: Thanks hannes! It worked great. I am curious to know your opinion on Rselenium. I have heard by others that it is terrible. But this seemed to work great!

Comment: I don't know, I am mostly using just a tool to get a job done. I also don't have that much experience, I just find it super cool to remote control a website ;-) :-)